# Bootstrap 5 dropdown toggle not working, cant figure out why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div className="dropdown">
              <a
                className="dropdown-toggle d-flex align-items-center hidden-arrow"
                href="#"
                id="navbarDropdownMenuAvatar"
                role="button"
                data-mdb-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="false">
                <img
                  src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/avatars/2.webp"
                  className="rounded-circle"
                  height="50"
                  alt="Black and White Portrait of a Man"
                  loading="lazy"
                />
              </a>
              <ul
                className="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end"
                aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuAvatar">
                <li>
                  <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    My profile
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    Settings
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    Logout
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

Nothing happens when I click the image(dropdown toggle). I have included the JS file too the css is rendering fine but the toggle isnt working and no dropdown items are showing:

```
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
```

Comment: Is any Bootstrap component working as expected in your application? Is it vanilla Javascript or do you use a Framework? For example `<a className="dropdown-item" href="#">` is not valid basic HTML, should be `<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">`

Comment: Yeah all the others are working fine (css). I am using react.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `data-mdb-toggle` with `data-bs-toggle`
and `d-flex` with `d-inline-flex` to open the menu in the right place.

```html
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"  rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>

<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
>
</script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <a
    class="dropdown-toggle d-inline-flex align-items-center hidden-arrow"
    href="#"
    id="navbarDropdownMenuAvatar"
    role="button"
    data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
    aria-expanded="false"
  >
    <img
      src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/avatars/2.webp"
      class="rounded-circle"
      height="50"
      alt="Black and White Portrait of a Man"
      loading="lazy"
    />
  </a>
  <ul
    class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end"
    aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuAvatar"
  >
    <li>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        My profile
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
          Settings
        </a>
     </li>
     <li>
         <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
            Logout
         </a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

For more:
Bootstrap v5 Documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#examples